# Excel VBA - Loop not importing data properly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a block of code that pulls customer transaction data from an HTML application, adds it together and imports the numbers to a spreadsheet. The code loops through a list of customer account numbers on the sheet but I'm having problems with the data that's being imported to the spreadsheet. Rather than importing the data and then looping to the next account it seems to loop through each account and import a total number of all the accounts rather than a total number for each individual account. Hopefully that makes sense, below is the portion of code that I think is causing the problem, I'm just not sure if something needs to be adjusted with the loop or if it's the ".Value" that are causing the problem. I would appreciate any advice/help I can get.

```
Dim lastRow As Integer

lastRow = Cells(10000, 6).End(xlUp).Row


rowData = 6 'set it to the first row of player account data
dblTotalSlot = 0
dblTotalTable = 0

For x = rowData To lastRow

' Navigate to Search screen
IE.navigate my_url2
If Not IEWait(IE) Then
    GoTo EndMe
End If

'check to see if user was successfully logged in
If Not IE.LocationURL Like "*search*" Then 'couldn't find the word 'Search' in the url, so it didn't make it here for some reason
    MsgBox "Please check your username/password is correct and try again.", vbCritical, "Error"
    GoTo EndMe
End If
IE.document.getElementById("accountNumber").Value = Me.Cells(x, 6).Value 'use the rowdata variable to get which row we are at
IE.document.getElementById("action").Click
If Not IEWait(IE) Then
    GoTo EndMe
End If
IE.navigate my_url3
If Not IEWait(IE) Then
    GoTo EndMe
End If
IE.document.getElementById("site").Value = Me.Cells(7, 4).Value
IE.document.getElementById("action").Click
If Not IEWait(IE) Then
    GoTo EndMe
End If
dblCustomerTTotal = 0
dblCustomerSTotal = 0
For i = 1 To 1
    Set TDelements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each TDelement In TDelements
        If TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsCustomerTContent" Then
            dblCustomerTTotal = dblCustomerTTotal + VBA.CDbl(TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText)
        ElseIf TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsCustomerSContent" Then
            dblCustomerSTotal = dblCustomerSTotal + VBA.CDbl(TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText)
        End If
    Next
    Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each e In elems
        If e.Value = "Next Results" Then
            e.Click
            If Not IEWait(IE) Then
                GoTo EndMe
            End If
            i = 0
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e
Next i
Me.Cells(rowData, 7).Value = dblCustomerTTotal
Me.Cells(rowData, 8).Value = dblCustomerSTotal
Me.Cells(rowData, 9).Value = dblCustopmerTTotal + dblCustomerSTotal
dblTotalT = dblTotalT + dblCustomerTTotal
dblTotalS = dblTotalS + dblCustomerSTotal

Next x

EndMe:
IE.Quit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
On Error GoTo 0 'reset the error handler
End Sub
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code line-by-line to see what its doing versus what you expect? this should help you understand the exact problem in the code.

Comment: Could provide an example dataset that shows what it's giving you and what you want instead?

Comment: Here's an example of what I get...

Comment: I don't see any edits...

Comment: Sorry hit enter by accident above... @CaffeinatedCoder what I have is a column of account numbers, the code should loop through each account and import the data from that account into the cell beside the account number before looping to the next account. It seems to be looping through each account and adding all the account data together and importing it at the end. I can't figure out why it's not importing the account data and then looping to the next account and so on.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder - Rather than importing the data from the first account and looping onto the next account and importing the data on the next line it seems to be looping through all the accounts and then importing the data as one value. I'd like to have an individual value for each account number... I can't see why it's not doing that.

Comment: After your `Next i` line, change all instances or `rowData` to be `x` instead.  For example, `Me.Cells(rowData, 7).Value = dblCustomerTTotal` should instead be `Me.Cells(x, 7).Value = dblCustomerTTotal`

Comment: Genius @tigeravatar!!!

Comment: That worked like a charm, you have no idea how thankful I am!!